# MySQL Workbench and limited SHOW privileges

Tags: mysql-workbench

I'm trying to use MySQL Workbench with shared MySQL server. Because it is shared, I have access only to my database and no SHOW DATABASES privilege.

This limitation causes Workbench to fail when filling Schemas toolbox with error

```
Error Code: 1227 Access denied; you need the SHOW DATABASES privilege for this operation
```

Is there any way to tell MySQL Workbench to scan only my database and prevent trying scanning for other databases?

Answer (score 0):

There is a setting in MySQL workbench preferences that could help your case. It's the `Show Schema Contents in Schema Tree` under SQL Editor section. 
It's supposed to decrease loading times by switching off enumerating, populating, and drawing of items, but switching off populating, may help you stop getting the access error.

More info about the config options and how to change it, in the [docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-sql-editor.html)

Comment: Unfortunately it works in different way. It does not stop scanning for databases, it just disables scaning for tables in databases. 

In other words — this options works on tables level, not databases level.